# return a function with partial argument embedded

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numpy-ndarray

I have a function which takes two numpy arrays, `x` and `y`, as arguments. I want to be able to pass in only one argument, `y`. How can I return a function that accepts `x`, with `y` embedded in original function?

For example:

```
def z(x: [x1, x2, x3], y: [y1, y2, y3]):
    return x1 * y1 + x2 * y2 + x3 * y3
```

I want `z(y=[2, 3, 4])` to return `x1 * 2 + x2 * 3 + x3 * 4` as a new function.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for deconstructing the arguments, by the way.

Comment: @chepner please tell me what the proper way is?  Thank you.

Comment: In the body, you need something like `x1, x2, x3 = x`.

Comment: Python 2 allowed you to write `def z((x1, x2, x3), (y1, y2, y3]): ...` (providing a tuple of names for the argument to unpack into *instead* of a single name). I miss that syntax sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>>  from functools import partial
>>> z_with_y = partial(z, y=[2,3,4])
>>> z_with_y([5,6,7])
56
>>> z([5,6,7], [2,3,4])
56
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `z = np.dot`, as in your example, or any other 2-arg function, you can make a partial fucuntion

```
def z1(y):
    return lambda x: z(x, y)
```

Without using `lambda`:

```
def z1(y):
    def inner(x):
        return z(x, y)
    return inner
```

Comment: I think you need to treat `z` as a black box, not knowing that it's computing a dot product.

Comment: @chepner. Good call. Not sure why I put `np.dot` in the return instead of `z`. Fixed now